# Prompt unsaved changes and cancel page transition

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using Jquery Mobile 1.3.1

I am using the onpagehide event to check for unsaved changes on the page and prompt whether to continue or not.  All of that works.  What I can't figure out is how to actually stop the page from transitioning to the new page when the user wants to stay on the page.

```
 $(document).on("pagebeforehide","#item_delivery_options", function(event, data) {
            if (unsaved_changes()){
                //yes, there are unsaved changes
                if(!prompt_unsaved_changes()){
                    console.log('stay on the page!'); // <-- I see this in the log !!!!
                    // now I want to stop the page transition,  HOW ????
                    event.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
```

I have tried replacing pagebeforehide with pagebeforechange but then the event doesn't fire at all

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it using the pagebeforechange event bound to all pages (the event is fired with every page transition) instead of just firing when the specific page is about to change like I was trying to accomplish.  Unless somebody can come up with something more efficient, this is my solution:

```
 $(document).on( "pagebeforechange", function( event, data ){
    if ( typeof data.toPage === "string" ) {
       if(data.options.fromPage[0].id == 'item_delivery_options'){
          if (unsaved_changes()){
             //unsaved changes
             if(! prompt_unsaved_changes()){
                console.log('stay on the page!');
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
             }
          }
     }
  });
```